# Lake Victoria Region Travel

Tags: visas, tanzania, kenya, uganda, lake-victoria

I will be visiting Jinja, Uganda in March 2017. My plan is to get an East African Visa at Entebbe Airport on landing. I will head north to Jinja, Uganda and then after a few days cross into Kenya at the land border between Jinja and Kisumu on the EA visa. Then a week or so later I will cross from Kenya to Tanzania over the land border on my way to Mwanza, Tanzania. Then finally a week later I will cross the land border into Uganda from Tanzania and head home from Entebbe.

Does anyone see any problems?

1) Is Uganda still issuing EA visas on arrival in Entebbe? I am traveling on USA passport and Yellow Fever certificate.

*EDIT - **Effective July 1, 2016, visas and residency permits will no longer be available at Entebbe Airport upon arrival.**
All visa and work permit (E-Visa and E-permits) applications must be completed via the Government of Uganda’s website. Under the new application process, you must apply online for all immigration services such as visas, permits, and passes at least two weeks prior to travel. The fee for a single entry tourist visa is $50 (https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/uganda.html).*

2) No issues I assume crossing into Kenya from Uganda at the land border as both countries are in the EA Visa program. Is this correct?

3) Any issue getting a 10-day Visa to enter Tanzania when I cross from Kenya into Tanzania at the land border? Again, on USA passport.

4) Finally, any trouble getting back into Uganda from Tanzania on my EA Visa as Tanzania is not in the EA Visa program. I assume I am allowed multlple re(entries) to Uganda on an EA Vsia.

Comment: Can you split this into 4 different questions?

Comment: @JonathanReez thanks, as each step could substantially alter the next I would prefer to keep as one question. For example, each part may be individually fine but not fine as a collective. You may not be able to reenter Uganda from Tanzania on an EA visa if you have transited through Kenya via a land border as opposed to flying as the Tanzania / Uganda land border may not have the same processing capability as the international airport at Entebbe (not unusual).

Comment: Planning your journey is out of the scope of this site. You may ask individual questions about each border and then decide what itinerary to choose.

Comment: In each question about a border you can include how you expect to get there, and whether you expect a different situation from flying in.

Comment: As EA visa regulations and border crossing procedures are opaque and have changed regularly over the last few years, with each individual country also not necessarily sticking to the agreements between the countries, and with different borders handling the same situation differently, OP's question, of rolling multiple border crossings into one problem, makes a lot of sense to me. Voted to reopen.

Comment: In case this doesn't get reopened: Your best bet is simply to go the official route, to keep your fingers crossed and to hope for the best. It seems that, currently, the EA visa only applies to Uganda, Kenya and Rwanda (http://www.visiteastafrica.org/visa-2/). Getting that, and a Tanzanian visa, while outside of these countries, at a consulate, will probably make your life easier. It might be more expensive, but few things are more annoying than, say, not being allowed in Uganda at the Mutukula border between Tanzania and Uganda. You should be able to get your TZ visa in Uganda.

Comment: @MastaBaba very helpful. I agree they seem very fluid. I'll probably take your advice. I do not think asking for LV travel information as opposed to a bunch of individual questions  is to broad. Actually, the question is very specific.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not sure how this could possibly be construed as asking anyone to plan my journey. My journey is 100% planned.  But hey. Each to their own.

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS: No prob. Last time I got a TZ visa in Uganda, it took a few hours, but this might have changed (and might be different for a US passport holder). If it's remotely possible, you should consider getting the visa back home.